# Chrome '`SameSite=None` warning in the console

Tags: google-chrome

I am not developing any website or anything. I just go to console from google chrome's default search page and this annoying warning pops up several times-

```
A cookie associated with a resource at http://google.com/ was set with 
`SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only 
deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You 
can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and 
see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

I am on a blank page only to write static js code and this pops up on each reload which is very annoying. How can I disable this warning so that it doesn't show up at all on the console. It very annoying to keep removing with clear console button.

Note: I would like to avoid installing CORS plugins. I just want to block or stop this annoying warning from console when I go to local pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you are not on a fully blank page, but the Google start page. As a result, these warnings are coming from the various resources loaded by the page. You can see the domains are generally `gstatic.com`, `google.com`, and so on. It's Google's responsibility to fix these warnings.

If you are on stable Chrome, then these warnings are purely informational and not affecting behaviour.

You can find more information on these particular changes at:

- https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained
- https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

To access a genuinely blank page, try popping `about:blank` into the address bar.